# When I sculpt it doesn't show in object mode

Tags: objects, sculpting, object-mode, sculpt

I am pretty new to blender. I am working on this character, however, everytime I switch from sculpt mode to object mode, it doesn't show the changes I made to the object in sculpt mode. I believe this might have started because I switched the "lock object mode" to off. I already turned it back on, but it still doesn't update. Please help.
[image: object mode]

[image: sculpt mode]

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Object Mode*, select the object, go to *Modifier Properties* and change *Level Viewport* value to bigger than zero until your modifications shows up in *Object Mode*.

[image]

This, it seems is an effect of using *Multires modifier*.

I found this solution in the answer [Why is object mode slow but sculpt mode fast?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107136/why-is-object-mode-slow-but-sculpt-mode-fast)